# phpMyAdmin routines not showing

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, xampp, routines

I have created a database and routines with MySQL Workbench. After I exported the SQL create script, I imported it into the phpMyAdmin, successfully executing 1065 queries, on my localhost XAMPP installation and it works perfectly, routines and all.

The problem is that when I try to do the same on a server at my workplace, the routines never show. There are no errors in importing the script, it executes the same 1065 queries with no errors, but when I go to the routines tab it doesn't show anything, just a blank screen, and doesn't even let me add new routines. I can't seem to figure out what the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the version of phpMyAdmin is different in both servers, so maybe you are trying to see the routines in a version that do not support them correctly.

For ensure that you correctly import your routines try selecting them:

```
SELECT routine_definition
FROM information_schema.routines
WHERE 
routine_name = 'routine_name' AND routine_schema = 'database_name';
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick help! It shows the routines if I do what you suggested me. Also, the phpMyAdmin versions are the same. I still get the upper tab on the screen (the menu) but the place where the routines should show is blank.

Comment: If it showing a blank screen I supose that there is a PHP fatal error in phpMyAdmin. Maybe the phpMyAdmin version you are using is not compatible with the PHP version the server has. Try showing or logging php errors in phpMyAdmin to check this.

Comment: I came across the same error now, and the problem was lack of memory. Your suggestion of it being a fatal error helped me. Thank you!